# How can I use Cypress for API testing applications written in Scala?

Tags: scala, cypress

Is it possible to use Cypress for testing an application written in Scala? I believe installing Cypress via 'npm install' requires node modules package added as well. So does it make sense to add npm node modules, package.json etc to Scala code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you'll need to explain what you tried and what didn't work to get help. Your question is too broad.

Comment: That being said, Cypress is first meant as a E2E test tool with UI. If you just want to test an API there are plenty of other alternatives that make more sense IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, Gael. I will update the description. My concern is can I add the package.json to a Scala code and npm install Cypress and add Cypress tests as I would for a node or react application.